# cocos2d-x error: 'glVertexPointer' was not declared in this scope

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-x

I've met the error when I build the cocos2d-x project with eclipse for the apk file.And I have used glVertexPointer(XXX)、glTexCoordPointer(XXX)、glDrawArrays(XXX)and opengl functions as so on.It's fine when run on the win32 platform.But when i build it for android .The error comes like that " error: 'glVertexPointer' was not declared in this scope".Here is the code:

---

```
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, m_fVertices);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, m_fTexCoords);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, (GLsizei)(m_iSegments+1));

glLineWidth(4);
glColor4f(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.0f);
```

Comment: I changed the glVertexPointer and glTexCoordPointer to glVertexAttribPointer. And it's ok. Anyone know the reason.